# python shelve is not saving/loading

Tags: python, pickle, shelve

When I save/load my workspace via functions in a subfile, shelve doesn't work (test1).
However, if I do the same in one file, it works (test2). Why is that? How can I fix the problem for the first case?

In the main file:

```
# in saveWS.py   

# to save
def saveSlv(fileName):
    destination='./'+fileName+'_shelve.pkl'
    bk = shelve.open(destination,'n')
    for k in dir():
        try:
            bk[k] = globals()[k]
        except Exception:
            pass
    bk.close()
        
# to restore
def loadSlv(fileName):
    myshelve ='./'+fileName+'_shelve.pkl'
    bk_restore = shelve.open(myshelve)
    for k in bk_restore:
        globals()[k] = bk_restore[k]
    bk_restore.close()
```

In the main file:

```
import shelve
# User defined functions
from saveWS import saveSlv, loadSlv 

# It doesn't work
a=1,2,3
b='ypk'
fileName='test1'
# save the variables in work space by calling a function
saveSlv(fileName)
del a, b
# restore the work space by calling a function
loadSlv(fileName)
 
# It works
a=1,2,3
b='ypk'
fileName='test2'

# save the variables in work space
destination='./'+fileName+'_shelve.pkl'
bk = shelve.open(destination,'n')
for k in dir():
    try:
        bk[k] = globals()[k]
    except Exception:
        pass
bk.close()
del a, b

# restore the work space
myshelve ='./'+fileName+'_shelve.pkl'
bk_restore = shelve.open(myshelve)
for k in bk_restore:
    globals()[k] = bk_restore[k]
bk_restore.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here's](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/functions.html?#globals) the `globals()`-related part of your problem (I guess):

> Return the dictionary implementing the current module namespace. **For code within functions, this is set when the function is defined and remains the same regardless of where the function is called.**

So `globals()` in your functions is always the namespace of `saveWS.py`.

And [here](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/functions.html#dir) the `dir()`-related one:

> Without arguments, return the list of names in the current **local** scope. With an argument, attempt to return a list of valid attributes for that object.

Therefore `dir()` refers to the local namespace *within* the function.

You probably could fix that by passing `dir()` and `globals()` as arguments:

```
def saveSlv(fileName, variables, namespace):
    destination='./'+fileName+'_shelve.pkl'
    bk = shelve.open(destination,'n')
    for k in variables:
        try:
            bk[k] = namespace[k]
        except Exception:
            pass
    bk.close()

def loadSlv(fileName, namespace):
    myshelve ='./'+fileName+'_shelve.pkl'
    bk_restore = shelve.open(myshelve)
    for k in bk_restore:
        namespace[k] = bk_restore[k]
    bk_restore.close()
```

Calling:

```
saveSlv(fileName, dir(), globals())
loadSlv(fileName, globals())
```

You could do without the `variables` argument by using

```
...
    for k in dir(sys.modules[namespace['__name__']]):
        ...
```

instead (after importing `sys`). In your usecase you could probably further replace `namespace['__name__']` with `'__main__'`. If you want to get rid of all the additional arguments you could try if this works for you:

```
import shelve
import sys

def saveSlv(fileName):
    destination='./'+fileName+'_shelve.pkl'
    bk = shelve.open(destination,'n')
    namespace = sys.modules['__main__'].__dict__
    for k in dir(sys.modules['__main__']):
        try:
            bk[k] = namespace[k]
        except Exception:
            pass
    bk.close()


def loadSlv(fileName):
    namespace = sys.modules['__main__'].__dict__
    myshelve ='./'+fileName+'_shelve.pkl'
    bk_restore = shelve.open(myshelve)
    for k in bk_restore:
        namespace[k] = bk_restore[k]
    bk_restore.close()
```

Check [here](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/__main__.html) if that's appropriate.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanations & insightful examples!